# How do I SELECT minimum set of rows to cover all possible values of each columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am running a SQL query to get data from a table to map all different possible values of all categories represented by each columns.

How do I run the SELECT query such that it returns the minimum number of rows just enough to include all possible values of all columns?

For example, if I have a table of 10 rows and 3 columns, each column containing 3 possible values:

```sql
TABLE sales
--------------------------------
   brandID   color       size
--------------------------------
    2        red         big
    3        blue        big
    2        blue        big
    2        red         small
    2        blue        medium
    3        green       small
    3        red         big
    1        green       medium
    2        red         medium
    2        blue        big
```

Of course I could SELECT all rows from table without filter, but that would be an expensive query of 10 rows.

However, as you can see, if we filter the SELECT query to only return the following rows below, it is possible to cover all the possible values of all columns:

1,2,3 for brandID

red,blue,green for color

big,small,medium for size

```sql
--------------------------------
   brandID   color       size
--------------------------------
    3        blue        big
    2        red         small
    1        green       medium
```

How do I do that in SQL query?

Comment: I don't understand how that example covers all possible values of all columns? What about `blue, small` and `blue, medium`?

Comment: As long as the returned table covers the following it satisfy my requirement: 

brandID - 1,2,3
color - blue,red,green
size - big,small,medium

order doesn't matter. The problem is how to use minimum number of rows to cover all those

Answer (score 3):

This one does what you expect:

```
select b.brandid, c.color, s.size
from (
  select brandid, row_number() over (order by brandid) as rn
  from sales
  group by brandid
) b
  full join (
    select color, row_number() over (order by color) as rn
    from sales
    group by color
  ) c on b.rn = c.rn
  full join (
    select size, row_number() over (order by size) as rn
    from sales
    group by size
  ) s on b.rn = s.rn;
```

Online example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e72e7d1dfed43825025c5703b5d3671a

---

But this only works properly, if you have the same number of (distinct) brands, colors and sizes. If you have e.g. 5 brands, 6 colors and 7 sizes the result is rather "strange":

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4417a4d97ecf7601364f09d65f6522fa

Comment: Hi, I'll upvote yours, as it is very close to mine and I *borrowed* your mcve from dbfiddle. However, I used COALESCE to avoid the *strange* result...

Answer (score 2):

First, a query that returns ten rows is not "expensive".

Second, this is a very hard problem. It involves looking at all combinations of rows to see if the set has all combinations of columns. I suspect that any algorithm will need to basically search through all possible combinations -- although there may be some efficiencies, such as automatically including all rows with a unique value in any column.

As a hard problem involving comparing zillions of sets, SQL is not really an appropriate language for addressing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather weird requirement... But you might try something along this:

```
DECLARE @sales TABLE(BrandID INT, color VARCHAR(10),size VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @sales VALUES
(2,'red', 'big'),
(3,'blue', 'big'),
(2,'blue', 'big'),
(2,'red', 'small'),
(2,'blue', 'medium'),
(3,'green', 'small'),
(3,'red', 'big'),
(1,'green', 'medium'),
(2,'red', 'medium'),
(2,'blue', 'big');

WITH AllBrands AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY BrandID) AS RowInx, BrandID FROM @sales GROUP BY BrandID)
    ,AllColors AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY color) AS RowInx, color FROM @sales GROUP BY color)
    ,AllSizes  AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY size) AS RowInx, size FROM @sales GROUP BY size) 
SELECT COALESCE(b.RowInx,c.RowInx,s.RowInx) AS RowInx
      ,b.BrandID
      ,c.color
      ,s.size
FROM AllBrands b 
FULL OUTER JOIN AllColors c ON COALESCE(b.RowInx,c.RowInx)=c.RowInx
FULL OUTER JOIN AllSizes s  ON COALESCE(b.RowInx,c.RowInx,s.RowInx)=s.RowInx;
```

This solution is similar to @a_horse_with_no_name's, but avoids gaps in the result in case of unequal counts of values per column.

The idea in short:

We create a **numbered set** of all distinct values per column and join all sets on this number. As we don't know the count in advance I use `COALESCE` to pick the first value, which is not null.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good problem if you demand ONE AND ONLY ONE query and ONE AND ONLY ONE of each result set, and ONE AND ONLY ONE instance of each result. As Gordon Linoff accurately put: that is not a problem for SQL.I get that maybe you have a MUCH larger table, but he's absolutely right.

But add another layer, and you can have exactly what you want, with all the efficiency you want, and a readable output. Use a cursor and some basic SELECT  from  dynamic SQL with a SELECT columns.name from sys.tables JOIN sys.columns ON tables.object_id = columns.object_id, if you absolutely have to do this with TSQL alone.

And if you're willing to build a basic application with any framework with a SQL driver, you can just SELECT DISTINCT  FROM < and put the various results into arrays.

Alternatively: reword your question, with the understanding that the results of any SQL query are gonna be x rows by x columns. Not an array for each column.

Comment: Do you mind showing me the cursor way to achieve this? I thought the examples provided was clear that I needed a table, not an array.

Comment: The point is, you can't do this in a table. If you have 10^6 distinct results from column A, 10^7 from column B, etc... (or literally any different totals), you can't build a 2-dimensional table with exactly one of each distinct result. If you want to know how to build a cursor on the columns of a table: DECLARE curs FOR SELECT columns.name, etc..., from the query I listed in my answer. Google cursors, and that will allow you to loop through columns on a table. But I still agree with Gordon; this is not a good question for SQL alone.

Answer (score 0):

I think your example confuses things by having exactly 3 values for each field, which makes the requested result seem like a reasonable thing to expect. But what happens when two more brands are added, or a new colour? Then what would you expect to be returned?

Really you are asking three questions, so I feel this should be done as three queries:

- "What are the different brands?"
- "What are the different colours?"
- "What are the different sizes?"

If they need to be displayed in a neat table, stitch them together afterwards in your application layer. You *could* maybe do it in the SQL with something like a_horse_with_no_name suggests, but really its the wrong place.